# Resources for doing an n dimensional FFT of a huge multi dimensional array

Tags: python, fft, distributed-computing, ram

I have a 50 dimensional array, whose dimensions are 255 x 255 x 255 x...(50 times)..x255. So its a total of 50^255 floating point  numbers. Its just out of scope to even think of fitting in a RAM. Moreover I need to take an 50 dimensional Fast Fourier Transform (DFT) of this array. I can't do it in python on an ordinary PC. I cant even imagine doing it on a GPU. so I am guessing I have to take help of a hard disk memory, but even that is too huge. I don't need this in real time, I can afford even days for it to run. I have no clue what sort of machine I need or is it even possible? Appreciate your advice. Super computers, grids, or something even if its too costly, I am not worried about investment.

Comment: It's 255^50, which if it's 32bit floats is about 8.4*10^120 bytes. Good luck finding somewhere to store all that data... at most there's 10^82 atoms in the universe. I think you'll run out of hard disk driives

Answer (score 2):

If you [found enough universes to save your data in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44878819/resources-for-doing-an-n-dimensional-fft-of-a-huge-multi-dimensional-array/44879499#comment76736398_44878819), here is what you could do:

The Fourier Transform is separable, that means that calculating the DFT of each axis one after the other will give you the same result as if you calculated the n-dimensional DFT:

```
for i in range(C.ndim):
    C[...] = numpy.fft.fft(C, axis=i)
```

Double checking if the value is correct using a 2D tensor (because we have a 2D FFT `numpy.fft.fft2` to compare against):

```
import numpy
A = numpy.random.rand(*[16] * 2)
B = numpy.fft.fft2(A)
C = A.astype(numpy.complex)  # output vector for separable FFT

for i in range(C.ndim):
    C[...] = numpy.fft.fft(C, axis=i)

numpy.allclose(C, B)  # True
```